# Javascript(easeljs) game development: make sure object is there to display it

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, browser-cache, easeljs

I'm working on a game and ran into yet another issue: I'm trying to render an image when something happened. I'm using easeljs to create the image like this:

```
var img = new createjs.Bitmap("../images/test.png");
img = 365;
img = 160;
img.scaleX = 0.5;
img.scaleY = 0.5;
stage.addChild(img);
```

This image is sometimes shown, but sometimes it isn't. Other images in the game work fine and I am rendering them the same way. The image is 4KB and is the smallest I have (others, bigger ones render OK).

Console shows no errors. I tried emptying cache, to no avail.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated since I really don't know what is wrong with this one.
If I was unclear, ask for more info please.

Thanks for any help

Comment: When a string path or image tag that is not yet loaded is used, the stage may need to be redrawn before it will be displayed.

Comment: Hey. I saw that yeah, but does this mean I have to manually redraw the stage? If so, i misunderstood this

Comment: And it has to be possible without redrawing everything? Like waiting for the image to load or something..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865628/easel-js-browser-compatibility-when-placing-an-image-within-a-container-and-add

Comment: that's it, damn! different thing, helped just the same. Or maybe its just the same thing given differently. thank you